# using panels to create custom page for all blogs

Tags: panels

I used panels to create static or landing pages, but now I'm wondering if it would be possible and how to create a custom page template for all blogs using panels, so a user would simply have to write a blog and not have to fuss without creating a specific panel variant for every blog page that is created.

thanks,

Chad

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the pre-provided `page` named `node_view`, it does exactly what you ask for. It loads any (and every) node then.

You can add what's called `selection rules` to limit to to certain content types, or based on other arbitrary conditions.